# Regex pattern to extract a String

Tags: java, regex

I've tried to extract the following string **`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets`** from the below text.

This is my solution so far : `\s+((\w:\\.*(?:\()))`

But this includes the `"("` in the extracted string. How do I get rid of the `"("`.

> **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets**(2015,5):
>   error MSB3091: Task failed because "AxImp.exe" was not found, or the
>   correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking
>   for "AxImp.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location
>   specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86. You may be able to solve
>   the problem by doing one of the following:  1) Install the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK.  2) Install Visual Studio 2010.  3) Manually set the
>   above registry key to the correct location.  4) Pass the correct
>   location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the non-capturing group at the last to positive lookahead.

```
\s*((\w:\\.*(?=\()))
```

OR

```
\s+((\w:\\.*(?=\()))
```

And i also suggest you to change the inbetween `.*` to `.*?` , `\s*((\w:\\.*?(?=\()))` in-order to provide a non-greedy match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iZ5kC7/2)